# Custom price for product, displayed in cart; not showing custom price in Review order page- in Multiple Shipping Checkout

Tags: magento

I am in a deep trouble, **I want to add different categories of product in cart, For each product I have to bring additional 5$ for additional quantity. It may differ in different category.**

**For the above case I have successfully implemented. But issue is that the price is not showing as that in cart in review order while opting multiple address checkout option.**

> for E.g:    there is two product 1 and 2.  for product 1 , for
>   additional quantity i have to add $5/qty excluding its original price
>   , i.e; if cost of product 1 is $10 and i selected 2 quantity then
>   price will be $10*2+($5*1)=25 . for product 2 , for additional
>   quantity i have to add $10/qty excluding its original price , i.e; if
>   cost of product 1 is 15 and i selected 2 quantity then price will be
>   $15*2+($10*1)=40 .
>
> ```
> I have implemented it.
> ```

**while proceeding with checkout option this price is showing fine.** **But when I opt multiple shipping its showing products original price,**

Is there anyway , to show the custom price in the review order also.

Please provide me help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: make a catalog price rule instead?

Comment: Okay, Is there any other way?. Because. It must not be viewed through admin panel also.

Answer (score 1):

Atlast I figure out the solution for this. All price for product displaying in cart is being set in **Subtotal.php** in

> [magento root]/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php

in **function  _initItem($address, $item)**, there I edit the set price for product with the custom price.

Now its working fine.

Hope it helps if someone needed it...